# numerous nested functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I've been reading about async functions in JavaScript and found out that I don't quite understand the following piece of code that comes from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Here it is:

```
doSomething(function(result) {
  doSomethingElse(result, function(newResult) {
    doThirdThing(newResult, function(finalResult) {
      console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
    }, failureCallback);
  }, failureCallback);
}, failureCallback);
```

What I don't understand is where all these results come from.

Comment: they are passed into the function when it's done, as an argument.

Comment: You're going to want to look into promises

Comment: @dandavis In which form? Would you please write down an example?

Comment: @SterlingArcher that code snippet came from a page explaining promises, hah.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Well promises are used to avoid structures like that but what I don't quite get is something else, namely the argument flow.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of JavaScript is that you already have all you need to test it.

The code you posted references 4 functions (don't forget the failure callback):

```
doSomething(function(result) {
  doSomethingElse(result, function(newResult) {
    doThirdThing(newResult, function(finalResult) {
      console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
    }, failureCallback);
  }, failureCallback);
}, failureCallback);
```

Those functions are not written. So let's write them:

```js
var failureCallback = function() {
  console.log('something went wrong');
}

var doSomething = function(callback) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var result = Date.now(); // Create some data that will change every time the function is invoked
    callback(result);
  }, 500);
}

var doSomethingElse = function(res, callback) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var result = [res]; // all this function really does is put the first argument in an array
    callback(result);
  }, 500);
}

function doThirdThing(res, callback) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    res.push(Math.PI); // res is supposed to be an array, so we can add stuff to it.
    var result = res;
    callback(result); // here we could have used res as a value, but I kept it consistent
  }, 500);
}

doSomething(function(result) {
  doSomethingElse(result, function(newResult) {
    doThirdThing(newResult, function(finalResult) {
      console.log('Got the final result: ', finalResult); // switched to a comma to display properly in the console
    }, failureCallback);
  }, failureCallback);
}, failureCallback);
```

To create some asynchronicity I used `setTimeout` so overall you have to wait 1.5 seconds.

The 3 functions that use a callback function as an argument, simply execute the function they were given. This is absolutely standard in JavaScript where functions are first class objects: you can pass them around as arguments like any other value type.

Answer (score 3):

They are *callbacks.*  A callback is just simply a function which is passed as an argument to another function and is used to do something with the result of some operation done by the function which receives the callback as an argument.  You can write your own.  A simple example:

```js
function callMe(callback) {
 let addition = 2 + 2;
 callback(addition);
}

callMe(function(result) {
 console.log(result);
});
```

`callMe` calls its callback function with the result of 2 + 2.  You then receive that result inside the callback function when you use `callMe`, and you can then write your own custom code to do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single threaded language, callbacks are used as a way to control the flow of execution when a asynchronous block of code ends in a non-blocking way. A callback is normally just another function (function B) that is passed into the asynchronous function (function A) to run when function A completes.  I.E

```
doSomething(func) {
 // do async code.
 // call func
 // func()
}
```

you haven't posted the inner blocks of those functions but i think we can all safely assume "result" is the response from the server passed back into the callback function I.E

```
doSomething(callback) {
    //fetch or ajax or whatever to server store response.
    //pass response BACK to callback function
    callback(response)
}
```